# RSpec deprecation warning: The implicit block expectation syntax is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I'am on upgrading a Ruby on Rails system from Rails 5 to 6 and as the first step I'm upgrading all gems. As I run my tests, I get the following message:

```
Deprecation Warnings:

The implicit block expectation syntax is deprecated, you should pass a block to `expect` to use the provided block expectation matcher (change `FileAsset.count`), or the matcher must implement `supports_value_expectations?`.
```

The test is passed, but I don't understand, what I have to do to avoid the deprecation message. The referenced block in my spec:

```
describe "Save should not create FileAsset" do
  subject {
    lambda {
      click_button I18n.t(:button_attach_files)
      page.should have_error_message()
    }
  }
  it { should_not change(FileAsset, :count) }
end
```

What should I use instead of `it { should_not change(FileAsset, :count) }`?

Current versions:

```
rails 5.2.8.1

rspec 3.12.0
rspec-activemodel-mocks 1.1.0
rspec-core 3.12.0
rspec-expectations 3.12.2
rspec-mocks 3.12.2
rspec-rails 5.1.2

cucumber 8.0.0
cucumber-ci-environment 9.1.0
cucumber-core 11.0.0
cucumber-cucumber-expressions 15.2.0
cucumber-gherkin 23.0.1
cucumber-html-formatter 19.2.0
cucumber-messages 18.0.0
cucumber-rails 2.6.1
cucumber-tag-expressions 4.1.0


rspec-support 3.12.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```rb
describe "Save should not create FileAsset" do
  subject {
    click_button I18n.t(:button_attach_files)
    page.should have_error_message()
  }
  it { should_not change(FileAsset, :count) }
end
```

Also you should prefer more recent syntax. Like:

```rb
describe "save" do
  it "does not create FileAsset" do
    expect { 
      click_button I18n.t(:button_attach_files)
    }.not_to change { FileAsset.count }
    expect(page).to have_error_message()
  end
end
```